# @synchronized and dispatch_async

Tags: ios, objective-c, synchronization, dispatch-async

What I'm trying to do is to use the `@synchronized` directive to protect a singleton object from being accessed by multiple threads at once. I also want to persistently store that singleton object by writing it to disk after each time it's modified, because it is very important that I try as hard as possible not to lose any changes to the object.

Now I know a lot of you might say don't do that; it takes too long; it's not a good practice, etc., etc. Yes, I am aware of that. This is more of a "what will happen?" question.

So whenever I go to modify the singleton object, I put the modification code inside a `@synchronized` block and then write the object to disk.  A thought I had was to use `dispatch_async` to do the writing of the object on a separate thread like so:

```
//singleton object
id dataStructure;

@synchronized(lockObject)
    {
        //code that modifies singleton object
        //not important

        //sharedFileQueue is a SERIAL queue
        dispatch_async([self sharedFileQueue], ^(void){
            NSError * err;

            NSData * plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:dataStructure
                                                      format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0
                                                      options:0 error:&err];

            //url to somewhere
            NSURL * url;
            BOOL success = [plist writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
        });

    }
```

So my understanding of `@synchronized` is that only one thread can execute that block of code at a time. My understanding of `dispatch_async` is a little fuzzy, but I think that this will submit the block to the dispatch queue to be executed asynchronously and return immediately. This means that if another thread comes through my `@synchronized` block while `dataStructure` is still being written to disk, it will just submit another block to run and write the newly modified `dataStructure` to disk, but that won't start until the first `dataStructure` is written to disk.

Am I thinking about this correctly?  Also will setting atomically change to `YES` or `NO` or will the serialization of my dispatch queue ensure that multiple threads won't be written to this file at the same time?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you read [this post](http://www.fieryrobot.com/blog/2010/09/01/synchronization-using-grand-central-dispatch/)?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

Dispatch queues themselves are thread safe. In other words, you can submit tasks to a dispatch queue from any thread on the system without first taking a lock or synchronizing access to the queue.

```
//singleton object
id dataStructure;

@synchronized(lockObject)
{
    //code that modifies singleton object
    //not important

    id dataStructureToWrite = [dataStructure copy];
    //sharedFileQueue is a SERIAL queue
    dispatch_async([self sharedFileQueue], ^(void){
        NSError * err;

        NSData * plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:dataStructureToWrite
                                                                    format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0
                                                                   options:0 error:&err];

        //url to somewhere
        NSURL * url;
        BOOL success = [plist writeToURL:url atomically:YES];
    });

}
```

Comment: Don't I need @synchronized for the code where I modify dataStructure? Are you saying I should put the code that modifies the dataStructure inside the block?

Comment: sorry I did not see you modify dataStructure in @synchronized block. I  do not think put the modifies in dispatch_async is a good idea. if the cost of copy dataStructure is cheap, you can copy a dataStructure for dispatch_async block, or the dataStructure you write may not in correct status.

Answer (score 0):

You at least need to synchronise the write on the lock object.  This is because the asynchronous block executes outside of the context of the `@synchronized{ ... }`.  This means that something else can change the data while it is being written which can lead to a logical inconsistency.

You probably also want some mechanism to check if the object has been modified since it was last written.  Otherwise, you'll find yourself doing unnecessary IO operations. e.g.

- Thread 1 modifies the object and puts a write on the queue.
- Thread 2 modifies the object and puts a write on the queue.
- Thread 1's write saves the mods from thread 1 and thread 2
- Thread 2's write saves the mods from thread 1 and thread 2 (which is the same as the last step)